# How do I fix hole on wood siding?

Tags: repair, wood, siding, patch

I installed a new outside light and took down the old light fixture. Now I have some holes on the wood siding. Some bigger area is about 1" to 1.5". What is the best way to patch them?

More info: the wood siding is clap board type with real wood about 1" thick.

Comment: What type of siding, shingles, clapboards T-111?

Comment: The repair depends on the type of siding you have, unless you wish to "patch" the immediate hole. Though that is not how I would recommend to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Best way is to find some more of the same (or similar) material, clean out or expand the hole to make it easy to patch, cut the new material to match and glue it in.  Caulk if necessary and paint to match.

Answer (score 0):

I would just fill them with wood filler, or less-expensive bondo -- prime, and paint.